# How to disable edit of all contact but allow creation of case?

Tags: civicase, access

I wish to create a role that is able to view all contacts, but unable to edit the contact details. However, this role should be able to create cases. I have tried the disable the access on "Edit All Contacts' and "Edit My COntacts". However, when I use disable the rule, I am unable to create case

Comment: Does the role have Civicase: add cases permission?

Answer (score 0):

The below works for me just if you don't have Add Contacts permission you have to visit the contact summary first and then choose Add Case from the Actions dropdown.

[image]

[image]